# How to change the background colour of a one particular listboxitem in a listbox in windows phone app?

Tags: windows-phone-7, windows-phone-8, windows-phone-7.1, windows-phone-7.1.1

i am developing an windows phone app.

I am having a listbox , in which depending upon on one particular condition i want to change only one listboxitem background colour .

Please Note :- i want to change background colour of only some listboxitems depending upon some particular condition.

Please let me know how i can achieve this ??

What are the various alternatives ??

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 2):

While you are binding the item sources to list box, add a property called background color and set this background color based on condition.

```
string background;
if(condition)
background="Red"; //Color you wish to set
List<ItemSet> source=new List<ItemSet>();

source.Add( new ItemSet(){ Background=background, OtherProperty=properties });
```

In the XAML you set the Background={Binding Background} for the list item.

If you have any issues let me know to it.